# Symfony2 : using Doctrine2 fixtures in a multilingual website

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, translation, fixtures

I have a multilingual website with 2 languages: en (default) and de (german).

I want to fill my categories table with default categories in english, using Doctrine Fixtures like this:

```
    $subcategory1 = new Category();
    $subcategory1->setTitle('Comedy');
    $subcategory1->setParent($category);
    $subcategory2 = new Category();
    $subcategory2->setTitle('Action');
    $manager->persist($subcategory1);
    $manager->persist($subcategory2);
    $manager->flush();
```

I am using Doctrine extension `translatable` to have the table content also in german. If I have to do it manually I have to do in symfony:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $category = $em->find('Tracker\MembersBundle\Entity\Category', 51 );
    $category->setTitle('Komödie');
    $category->setTranslatableLocale('de'); // change locale
    $em->persist($category);
    $em->flush();
```

My question is how can I automate this process to make it work while loading fixtures? I have about 30 categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method:

```
$subcategory1 = new Category();
$subcategory1->setTitle('Comedy');
$subcategory1->setParent($category);
$subcategory2 = new Category();
$subcategory2->setTitle('Action');

$manager->persist($subcategory1);
$manager->persist($subcategory2);
$manager->flush();

$subcategory1->setTranslatableLocale('de_DE');
$subcategory1->setTitle('ComedyDE');
$subcategorys->setTranslatableLocale('de_DE');
$subcategory2->setTitle('ActionDE');
$manager->flush();
```